# Array of chars?

Tags: postgresql, array, database-internals

Can we create an array of chars in postgresql i.e (Column_name char[5]) and does it take only 5 bytes in disk ? since type char takes only one byte

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with that? Why an array to begin with?

Comment: "*since type char takes only one byte*" - no, it does not. A single char might need more then one byte depending on the character set you are using.